# Android Serializable loses it's type

Tags: java, android, serialization, bundle

I add a bundle to intent like this:

```
bundle.putSerializable("cars", mAllCars.toArray(new Car[mAllCars.size()]));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

I deserialize my "cars" like this:

```
Serializable test = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("cars");//for testing purposes
Car[] cars = (Car[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("cars");
```

On my Nexus 5x, `test` is Car[xxx] with Car{...} items, however, on LG G2(4.4), and 4.4 Emulator, `test` is Object[xxx], though, items still are Car{...}, so I get a ClassCastException. 
[image: Nexus 5x]
[image: LG G2]

I'm thinking about casting each item separately when array is not of type Car, but I still would like to find out what causes this issue.

Comment: Unless you are also using this stuff for persistence, you might wish to use `Parcelable` anyway, for runtime performance.

Comment: To add on to what @CommonsWare mentioned about using Parcelable, by far the easiest solution I've found to sending arrays of custom objects through intents is to use Google's Gson library to simply serialize the data into a JSON String, and then just pass that single string through the intent. It only takes a couple of lines to serialize/de-serialize using Gson, and it removes a lot of the headaches of dealing with the limitations of the Bundle/Intent system.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but I'm more interested in knowing why this happens.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe, yes that is one of the easiest way to do it. As Parcelable does create some delay

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3847